# Фильтрация строк Google Sheet по группам (разделенные пустыми строками). Фильтрация объединенных записей

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-docs

Имею данные в Google Sheet:
[image]

Я получаю данные в формате выше. Таким образом, записи агрегируются из разных источников. Одна запись фактически представлена ​​одной строкой текста в столбцах **B-H** . Данные разделены по записям от **Менеджера 1** до **Менеджера 2** и так далее. Но столбцы **I-L** имеют несколько строк и относятся к одиночным записям в группе.

Установил цвета чтобы было видно каждую индивидуальную запись:
[image]

***SourceSheet** (образец данных) доступен: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JqsV1upqVZ1FaVfdaQ9IoECGJytmdwwkvFZPT0AdOGg/edit?usp=drive_link)*

---

Мне нужно фильтровать эти данные по столбцам **B-H** . Когда я фильтрую, как обычно, фильтруется только одна строка. Как выполнить фильтрацию по сгруппированным записям, разделенным пустыми строками?

Например, если я фильтрую на основе **Менеджера 1**, я получаю результат:
[image]

Можно ли реализовать это с помощью стандартного фильтра **Google Sheet** или **Googe Apps Script**?

Comment: Также вам дали несколько ответов на [англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78119965/15603838)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @Alexander Kouleshov, для фильтрации нужен ключ.
Столбец с ключом должен быть полностью заполнен. Вот Вам варинант, где можно выбрать сразу несколько столбцов, которые будут заполнены, и соответственно которые можно будет использовать в качестве ключа для фильтрации.[image: Вот так это будет выглядеть]

Формула:`=let(key;"Manager|Clinic"; BYCOL(Filtering!B3:L;LAMBDA(_col; if(REGEXMATCH( CHOOSEROWS(_col;1);key);SCAN(;_col;LAMBDA(acc;x;IF(x<>"";x;acc)));_col))))`

Comment: Кода заполняются пустые строки по последнему элементу там все пустые строки до конца листа (1000 строк) заполняются значениями последнего элемента. И при фильтрации последнего элемента выводится не одна запись а все 1000 строк заполненных. Это можно как то скорректировать?

Comment: Да, легко. Замените в вышеприведенной формуле Filtering!B3:L на QUERY( Filtering!B3:L;"Where I is not null")

Answer (score 1):

Организация Вашей таблицы исключает возможность использовать встроенный фильтр по озвученным критериям. Моё предложение - "велосипед": преобразовывать массив, чтобы в строках был хоть один уникальный ключ для возможности фильтровать нужные диапазоны. Попробуйте на новом листе в ячейку A1 такую формулу (авось поможет). Это даст возможность устанавливать нужный фильтр по манагеру:

```
=IFNA(HSTACK('Filtering 2'!B3:C;{"Manager";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW('Filtering 2'!D4:D);IF(LEN('Filtering 2'!D4:D);HSTACK(ROW('Filtering 2'!D4:D);'Filtering 2'!D4:D););2));COUNTA('Filtering 2'!I4:I);1)};'Filtering 2'!E3:L);)
```

Answer (score -1):

В доп. столбец:

```
=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(B$4:B4;">0")
```

Или для текстовых записей:

```
=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(C$4:C4;"?*")
```

Можно применить `СЧЕТ()`, `СЧЕТЗ()`

Фильтрация по этому столбцу